# Why is my Objective-C object being deallocated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

I have a problem with an Objective-C object (in an iOS game app) that is being mysteriously deallocated.

The object is a GameCharacter instance which is instantiated like so:

```
for (int c = 0; c < kNrOfGuards; c++) {
    GameCharacter* guard = [[GameCharacter alloc] initGuard:self sprite:guardSprite];
    [characterArray addObject:guard];
    [guard release];
}
```

I also have a convenience method for finding a GameCharacter:

```
- (GameCharacter*)findCharacterWithIndex:(int)index {
    return [characterArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

And the code that generates the error looks like:

```
for (int c = 0; c < [self characterCount]; c++) {
    GameCharacter* tempCharacter = [self findCharacterWithIndex:c];
    if (tempCharacter.playerId == playerIndex]) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Running this code *for some time* (never immediately) generates an error in the Console:

**[GameCharacter playerId]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4e47560**

With the [NSZombieEnabled trick](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone) I've managed to track down the object(s) that is causing the problem, but I still can't understand *why* this object is being deallocated. Searching my code for "release"/"dealloc" does not produce any clues.

I've tried removing the "release" (and even adding a "retain"!) to the alloc/init loop (see top), it seems to extend the time the app can run but not remove the problem entirely.

Any hints would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Thanks to quixoto, Olie, Eiko, tc., I've figured out that it is my GameCharacter object that is being deallocated, but I still don't understand quite why. Here is the trace log in reverse chronological order:

```
#0 -[GameCharacter dealloc]
#1 objc_setProperty
#2 -[TiledGroundLayer setSelectedCharacter:]
#3 -[TiledGroundLayer selectNextCharacterForPlayer:searchStep:]
#4 -[GameScene selectNextCharacter:]
#5 -[GameScene endTurn]
#6 -[HUDLayer onClickDone:]
```

What happens here, is that the user clicks "Done", the selected character on screen is changed and thus the property `selectedCharacter` on TiledGroundLayer (step #2-4). Since `selectedCharacter` owns the previous GameCharacter object, it seems it is being deallocated. But why is it not being retained properly by the NSMutableArray (`[characterArray addObject:guard];`)?

Comment: Was your characterArray variable created as `[NSMutableArray array]` or `[[NSMutableArray init] alloc]`?

Comment: @Tom - in which classes do these code snippets live?  It looks like you have code elsewhere that interacts with the characterArray resulting in the dealloc.  Could be associated with removal of the object from the array for example - does that happen?

Comment: I would look carefully at characterArray and when it is deallocated. Since you have a convenience function to return a guard you could easily be holding onto it after characterArray and all its contents are deallocated. If you didn't have the convenience method (and I can't see its benefit here) you could instead just grab the guard from the array whenever you need it and be more sure that characterArray was still required and valid at that point.

Comment: Stick a breakpoint at the top of the `dealloc` method in `GameCharacter`. You'll see who pulls the last release, anyways.

Comment: @jojaba: it's created as `characterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: Is it possible that you remove those characters from the array, but still hold references to those objects and work with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your update:

```
#0 -[GameCharacter dealloc]
#1 objc_setProperty
#2 -[TiledGroundLayer setSelectedCharacter:]
```

I would guess that you're releasing your existing reference to an object in your setter, followed by retaining the new copy. However, if the new object happens to be the exact same object as the existing reference, you might be sending the `retain` message to an already deallocated object.

```
-(void) setSelectedCharacter: (GameCharacter*) newCharacter
{
  [character release]; // Oops if character == newCharacter
  character = [newCharacter retain];
}
```

Comment: The property is defined as: `@property (nonatomic, retain) GameCharacter* selectedCharacter;` - wouldn't the "retain" part take care of this?

Comment: Paul Alexander, you're absolutely right! It was the "retain" part of `@property (nonatomic, **retain**)` that released the object prematurely. By changing it to "assign" instead, the problem is solved. Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Just to be clear, changing it to assign (from retain) changes the behaviour of the code.  You may have fixed THIS bug, but be careful that you didn't just introduce a dozen others.

Comment: What Paul was trying to describe is this: In his example code, imagine that character and newCharacter are the same object.  The first line of the function releases NEWCHARACTER, then the 2nd line attempts to retain a retained object.  The correct order to do that function is this:  id oldCharacter = character; character = [newCharacter retain]; [oldCharacter release];   See?

Answer (score 4):

There's not quite enough code here to tell what the problem is but, from the error message, I'd guess that the playerId object is what's not being retained.  That is, it seems that your tempCharacter is fine, but not the playerId field.

If you have

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) SomeObject *playerId;
```

then remember that

```
playerId = foo;
```

will **NOT** hold onto the object for you.  You must use the accessor:

```
self.playerId = foo;
```

**EDIT** in response to Tom's question-edit:

I absolutely, positively guarantee you that objects placed in an NSMutableArray are retained by that array until (a) they are removed or (b) the array is released.  So you can stop looking there, the problem is somewhere else.   :)

One thing you can try is to add the following code to the object that is being released when you think it shouldn't:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory-use debugging

#define DEBUG_RETAIN_RELEASE    0
#define DEBUG_ALLOC_DEALLOC     0



#if DEBUG_ALLOC_DEALLOC

static int allocCounter = 0;
+(id)alloc
{
    id me = [super alloc];
    NSLog(@"%@ ALLOC (%2d):   %@", [me class], ++allocCounter, me);

    return me;
}

#endif


#if DEBUG_RETAIN_RELEASE
- (id)retain
{
    id result = [super retain];
    NSLog(@"%@ retain      %@, count: %2d", [self class], self, [self retainCount]);
    return result;
}


- (void)release
{
    // we have to log BEFORE the release, in case it's the last one! e
    NSLog(@"%@ RELEASE     %@, count: %2d", [self class], self, ([self retainCount] - 1));
    [super release];
}


- (id)autorelease
{
    id result = [super autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@ AUTOrelease %@, count: %2d", [self class], self, [self retainCount]);
    return result;
}

#endif

// ...


- (void)dealloc
{
#if DEBUG_ALLOC_DEALLOC
    NSLog(@"%@ dealloc (%2d): %@", [self class], --allocCounter, self);
#endif

    [self releaseMyStuff];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Then start with DEBUG_ALLOC_DEALLOC = 1 and put a breakpoint on the dealloc log statement.  If that doesn't help, set DEBUG_RETAIN_RELEASE = 1 and break on both retain & release.

You'll be surprised at all the iOS retains you get, but don't worry about it, iOS promises balanced retain-release, if used properly.  I'm just warning you because you may be expecting a much lower retain count, and be surprised to see it climb during some operation or another.

Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Debugging spurious retains/releases in 3 easy steps:

1. Override `-retain`, `-release`, and `-autorelease` for the class you are interested in. Make them log a message (`NSLog(@"%@ %s", self, sel_getName(_cmd))`) and `super`-call.
2. Breakpoint all these methods (at the `super`-call, i.e. after the log message so you know which object it is). Edit the breakpoint; add the command "bt" and check the auto-continue box (or just use two commands "bt", "continue").
3. Clear the log. Run the app. Print out the log. Stick it to a whiteboard. Draw some arrows until you find the spurious `release`/`autorelease`.

My first impression was that `characterArray` was being released too early, but that should result in it complaining about sending a message to a deallocated NSArray. Unless, of course, you're accessing `characterArray` from multiple threads (don't do that!).

Answer (score 0):

You release your GameCharacter instance somewhere. Your code looks ok, so it's somewhere in the other places that uses those objects.